# Importing CMake Project into Clion, Unable to find BOOST_ROOT

Tags: compilation

I get the following error when importing eos (1.0 from github) as a clion project.  Does anyone know where I can set BOOST_ROOT?

`/home/usera/clion-2018.1.3/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /home/jack/eos
-- Using custom FindBoost.cmake
CMake Error at libraries/fc/CMakeModules/FindBoost.cmake:1129 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
  Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
  directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
  Boost's headers..`

Answer (score 2):

I think it has to do with the most recent EOSIO git repo having the boost root as `~/opt/boost` and the CMake is looking for something like `~/opt/boost__1__6__6`

The way I solved this is by importing the entire EOSIO folder into Clion (after doing `./eos_build.sh` and `sudo ./eos_install.sh`) and going to 
File ==> Settings ==> Build, Execution, Deployment ==> CMake

and putting inside CMake options: 

`-G Ninja -DBOOST_ROOT=~/opt/boost -DWASM_ROOT=~/opt/wasm -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/bin/openssl bin-DBUILD_MONGO_DB_PLUGIN=true -DENABLE_COVERAGE_TESTING=false -DBUILD_DOXYGEN=false`

I think this overrides the CMakelists files by explicitly telling Clion  where to look for Boost with

`-DBOOST_ROOT=~/opt/boost`